# How to check if an element is the last with this class?

Tags: javascript

So if I have a list of elements and I want to find out which one of them is the last one with this class. How can I do it without JQuery? Maybe I can get its index somehow?

in JQuery it would be something like that:

```
<div class="div">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
<div class="div">3</div>
<div class="div">4</div>
<div class="div">5</div>
<div>6</div>

jQuery(document).on('click', '.div', function() {
if ( $(this).is($(".div:last")) ) 
{
   console.log($(this))
}    
});
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g0zLsfzy/)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either do that what you did, using the 'querySelector'

```
var lastElem = document.querySelector('div.class-name:last-child');
```

Or you could do something like this -

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class-name');
var lastElem = elements[elements.length - 1];
```

Comment: Zero is first: `elements.length - 1`

Comment: @jadeallencook Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard query function, which accepts CSS selector syntax:

```
divs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');
last_div = divs.item(divs.length - 1);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).